# Json response severe error in jersey REST application

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey

I'm learning JERSEY REST API with maven. I'm getting following error whey i hit GET request. Interesting point is when i return only specific class object, i'm getting the desired result but when i return a map of all those objects i'm getting this error with Status 500 - Internal Server Error. Please suggest.

Error:

```
SEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, 
type=class java.util.HashMap, genericType=java.util.Map<java.lang.Integer, message.Message>.
```

Error prone:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Map<Integer,Message> getAll(){
    ms.sample();
    return ms.getAllMessages();

}
```

Same code but returning specific object, works fine:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Message getAll(){
    ms.sample();
    return ms.getAllMessages().get(1);

}
```

P.S : I've added json related element in pom.xml file as follows

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

I'm using Maven v2.16

Comment: do you have jackson dependency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MOXy and `Map`s are not friends... I recommend you using Jackson instead of MOXy to (de)serialize JSON.

To do it, remove the `jersey-media-moxy` dependency and add the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.23.1</version>
</dependency>
```

For more details, check [Jersey documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json.jackson).

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But one more, why pom.xml file have the default moxy related element then?

Answer (score 0):

Add following dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>

</dependency>
```